# Positioning arrowheads at beginning and end of double line in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Why are the arrowheads placed as they are in the figure below? I.e. why are they not placed at the exact beginning and end of the path?

[image]

Code used:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double distance=15, thick,
            postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0 with {\arrow{Straight Barb[reversed,length=0pt 0.7]}}}},
            postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow{Straight Barb[length=2pt 0.7]}}}}
        ] (0,2) -- node {FOO}(5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For reference, how I want it to be:

[image]

Comment: `double distance` causes the problem. Even with a single line, results are not the expected ones, are they? Not exactly the same, but did you look the `double arrow`shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placement of arrows with `double` lines is difficult (read not possible). Here you have to do some manual adjustments. Here is the first attempt using `xshift`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double distance=15, thick,
            postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0 with {\arrow[xshift=5mm]{Straight Barb[reversed,length=2pt 0.7]}}}},
            postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[xshift=7mm]{Straight Barb[length=2pt 0.7]}}}}
        ] (0,2) -- node {FOO}(5,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is the second acrobatics:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double distance=15](8pt,2) -- (5cm-8pt,2);   %% this length needs to be adjusted.
    \draw[double distance=15,
            {Straight Barb[black,length=2pt 0.7 0.2].}-{.Straight Barb[length=2pt 0.7 0.2]}
        ] (0,2) -- node {FOO}(5,2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

So depending upon what do you want, you may also be interested in the `double arrow` shape as commented by Ignasi.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [double arrow,draw, text width=5cm,align=center] {FOO};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why is placement difficult?

Comment: @percusse Not difficult? I took it from the manual, it says so. :)

Comment: It says *On double lines, the arrow tip will not look correct.* Not difficult or else.

Comment: @percusse: I take it as difficult in the sense we have to do extra work. Any thing that requires extra work is difficult in my dictionary as I am lazy :P

Comment: This is not a double line arrow. It is a decoration.

Comment: @percusse You have any solutions? I am curious.

Comment: I don't have access to TeX in the evening I might. But your comment is misleading regardless.

Comment: @percusse Unless it is proved :) Nevertheless, feel free to change that line. I won't mind :)

Comment: Place any other thing than arrow head and it works as a decoration which is a proof of double line is not the problem. It's an arrow inset setting that I need to check.

Comment: @percusse We are talking about arrows only here. If you can spend time on this and dig things for a solution that will be really helpful. I don't understand why Till just stopped with that line without pursuing the matter.    Any solution for this will deserve a bounty (I will give). If you have time, please go ahead.

Comment: These days I'm just reading on the phone. I also installed Ubuntu and feeling like an idiot as I am desperately trying to learn Linux. I'll check when I find a Windows machine to speed things up.