# Draw special arrow with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I searched to find a simple way of drawing something like the figure below using tikz, but I couldn't find. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All one has to do is too search within this site...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276565/positioning-arrowheads-at-beginning-and-end-of-double-line-in-tikz
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] at (0,0) (A) {A}; 
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] at (4,0) (C) {C}; 
\draw[double distance=15, thick,
        postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0 with {\arrow[xshift=5mm]{Straight Barb[reversed,length=2pt 0.7]}}}},
        postaction={decorate, decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[xshift=7mm]{Straight Barb[length=2pt 0.7]}}}}
    ] ([xshift=1em] A.east) -- node {B} ([xshift=-1em] C.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276565/positioning-arrowheads-at-beginning-and-end-of-double-line-in-tikz
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] at (0,0) (A) {A}; 
\node[draw, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm] at (6,0) (C) {C}; 
\node[double arrow,draw, text width=3.2cm,align=center] at (3,0) (B) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway for removing the vertical lines of box around B? They make the figure a little bit ugly.

Comment: I found the solution to my question at the link you provided within your code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And what if we want to only have -> on one side of the arrow? I mean instead of <-->, we want -->. How can we do that?

Comment: @m0_as use `arrownode` defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166860/how-to-bend-a-tikz-node)